# My scriptableobject not save when I build the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use scriptable as save for my game.
When I play on editor everything look good not problem here but when I build the scene some value on scriptable be reset to 0 I don't know why but sometime it not happen can someone help me on this?

When I play the built scene it can't save at all when I quit and play again the int value always reset

Please help me

```
public class Base_GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
    #region Vairable
    public Base_UI_Manager UI;
    public Base_Scriptable_Holder Game_Data;
    #endregion
}

public class Base_Scriptable_Holder : ScriptableObject
{
    [Header("BeSet")]
    public Base_Player_Global Player_Global;
    public List<Base_Player_Country_Data> Player_Areas ;
    public List<Base_Universal_TreeSystem_Data> Trees;
    [Header("Setting")]
    public List<Base_Area_Data> Areas;
    public List<Base_Product_Data> Products_Data;
    public List<Base_Construction_Data> Construction_Data;
    public List<Base_Theory_Data> Theories;
    [Header("InspectOnly")]
    public GameObject GO;
    public int LastProduct;
    public int LastConstruction;
    public int LastTheories;
}

[Serializable]
public class Base_Player_Product
{
    public string Name;
    public int Worker;
}

void AssignEmp(int index)//I assign this method to a button
{
        GM.Game_Data.Player_Areas[GM.Country_index].Products[index].Worker++;
        UI_Product_Panel_Update();
}

public void UI_Product_Panel_Update()//Update Product panel
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GM.Game_Data.Products_Data.Count; i++)
    {
        Products[i].transform.GetChild(4).GetComponent<Text>().text = GM.Game_Data.Player_Areas[GM.Country_index].Products[i].Worker.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Worked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be useful to actually see some code if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. You will also need to provide more detailed information about your problem, what have you tried so far and what exactly got wrong, along with a [mcve].

Comment: Ok  I mean why my scriptableobject not save when I built the game and play quit and play again the int value always rest ( first time I add change a number from 0 to 5 when I quit and player again it go to 0 agian) and when I play on the editor it go to 0 too I'll add the code at the post.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't allocate memory for your List's? `Player_Areas = new List<Base_Player_Country_Data>()`

Comment: I allocated on other method.